# RegEx replace in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm pretty new to regular expressions. I've worked out the string `(?i)\$url\[([0-9])\]` to match what I'm looking for. I want a string like `"this is $url[2] a string"` to be passed through that regex, have `2` passed to a function, which returns a string, and `$url[2]` is replaced with that string. How do I do that?

Comment: Does the regex work? Have you learned Python? What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def myrepl(match):
    num = int(match.group(1))
    # Do something here
    return str(num) # this will replace the $url[2]

mystr = "this is $url[2] a string"

print re.sub(r'\$url\[([0-9])\]', myrepl, mystr, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```